# Arguments in java script

Tags: javascript

How can I remove one argument from the argument object in javascript?

I want the final arguments to be an arguments object and not as array.

Thanks

Comment: example : i have a function which get Unknown number of arguments, from this function i need to send to another function all the arguments except of the first one.

Comment: Than its no problem to convert the agruments array to a default array. My other answer will fit you problem.

Comment: please post some code as example, which would make it more clear for people to understand

Comment: what are you talking about? arguments? you mean variables?

Comment: @Ark `arguments` is a variable injected into each function's execution scope. It includes the arguments passed to a function (`a(1, 2)` -> `[ 1, 2 ]`). The problem is that this list is not an Array, it's only Array-like.

Comment: @IanKuca those are params to me, not arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
var args = toArray.apply(null, arguments);
args = args.slice(1, args.length); // here you have an arguments array minus the first

myFinalFunction.apply(null, args); // call your second function this way

// helper function
var toArray = function() {
    var args = [];
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) args.push(arguments[i]);

    return args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function from a wrapped function and leave the first argument out.

Comment: How can I leave the first out?

Comment: That why people ask for an example. If you know how mutch params you got, its easy. function(a,b,c) { myFunc(b,c);}

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = function () {
  var args;
  var b = function () {
    args = arguments;
  };

  var orig = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  orig.splice(1, 1); // remove one argument
  b.call(this, orig);

  console.log(args); // [ 1, 3 ]
};

a(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

​You can something like below to remove first arguments

```
function addMe(){
   var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

   var first_arg = arg.shift(); //remove first argument
   alert(arg); //new arguments
}

addMe(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```